# Create files with specific mime type

Tags: linux, file, mime-types, mime

I was wondering if there's a way to create files with specific mime types like
'.wpf', '.pub', '.wmf', '.emf', '.hdp', '.jpc', '.msg','.xps', '.oxps', '.xml', '.xod', '.xaml' and '.jp2'

I am unable to find sample files online and download them to test my app's file type and mime type recognition functionality.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of a "file" is simply some data which belongs to some metadata and that metadata includes a file name and might also include some other stuff like permissions and time stamps.

A file by itself does usually not contain any information about mime types, but its file name might include an extension which might give a hint (right or wrong) about the file content.

Mime types is rather a concept used when a web server sends data to a web client to tell the client how the data should be used. The data that the server sends to a client might be taken from a file or dynamically generated by the web server.